# Added a Comment to an answer, and voted -1 to the answer and got the Organizer Badge

Tags: bug, comments, badges, down-votes

I added a comment to the first answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049660/changing-performancepoint-time-intelligence-post-formula-default-value), voted it down and won an Organizer badge?

However I didn't retag it as the description of the badge says. I think this is a bug

So this is probably a bug, what should I do?

**EDIT:** So did anyone found out why I won this badge?
Did the previous user retag the question and when I voted down I got the badge on his behalf?

Comment: Not sure what's going on with this. In your activity history, I don't see any retagging at all. Is this your only user account? I know the powers-that-be have been doing some account merging lately, and you may have been awarded that badged on another account.

Comment: This is my only account.

Comment: So if this is a bug, what should I do, simply by posting it here is it reported or should I do something to report this as a bug?

Comment: Ho-ho. Planned since 2011.

Comment: @Nick 5 years later, is this still planned? If not, can you please remove the tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Took a while but I think that I've figured out the real bug. As can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer?userid=181969):

> [image]

You got the badge for [totally different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1562236/447356) (<sup>10K only</sup>) than what you thought and the badge was awarded **as a result of you deleting the question**. Your other actions (commenting, downvoting) are totally irrelevant, you could also blame the coffee you were drinking. ;-)

In that question [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1562236/revisions) I do see one old revision where you changed tags but as part of bigger edit, so it did not count as "retag" at the time.

As far as I can tell, this is an edge case where the delete process trigger kind of "badge recalculate" task that wrongly identifies edits that change tags (but not only tags) as retag.

Comment: lol those features that show why and where the badge was awarded, cool btw. Tks to SO devs. So Retag of my own questions grants the Organizer Badge.

Comment: @GabrielGuimarães yeah, retag of any question - but note there is different badge for *editing*.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a definite bug considering you have less than 250 rep. You can't even retag normal questions (though you can edit CWs) and I looked at your activity history(along with @Jon) and did not find any retagging.

Comment: The question was posted by me, maybe I can retag it because of that, but was the question retagged at all by anyone? I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

This will be fixed in an upcoming build, with an overhaul of the badge code.  I'm going through each query and caught a few edge cases and bugs here and there.  We're fixing them along the way, this one included.

Comment: *Pssst, hey NickCraver.  Was this ever completed, or is it status-planned still?*

Comment: This is the oldest question with the [status-planned] tag. Is it still planned?

Comment: This has been planned for a LONG LONG time...

Comment: Nick, did I nail the bug down [in this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198995/152859)? And was it fixed by now? :)

Comment: I totally understand if you can't/won't fix a bug. But saying you will, then ignore all comments asking for updates? No.

Comment: @Doorknob and judging by the 100% ignore rate, will still be planned in 100 years as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it takes a few minutes for badges to show up. It is likely that you previously re-tagged a question.

Comment: I didn't retag the question.

Comment: @Chao "In your activity history, I don't see any retagging at all."