# Is this a Bug on StackOverflow Time calculation?

Tags: support, questions, timestamps

I've entered a question yesterday and Meta StackOverflow says it was submitted 22 hours ago,
and it's 15:00 on my local time, however Meta StackOverflow says the question has been asked today.

[Question referenced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48028/added-a-comment-to-an-answer-and-voted-1-to-the-answer-and-got-the-organizer-ba)

[Example http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/6508/timebug.png](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/6508/timebug.png)

Comment: You may like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12635/greasemonkey-script-to-display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time

Comment: Firefox “Personas” make my pony's eyes bleed.

Comment: that was a bad idea to use imageshack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you see in the system is not localized to your time zone, so the time when a new day starts according to the site may not necessarily be the same as when a new day starts for you.

As it says on your recent activity page (click the envelope at the top), all times listed are in UTC.

Comment: So Stackoverflow can't say to me that the question has been asked today because saying that way is a localized answer.

Comment: It HAS been asked today. It's not SO's fault that you use crazy moon time.

Comment: @mmyers: 23/24ths of the planet are part of the Moon?

Comment: Have more pity for the poor guy in Tonga (near the international dateline, UTC+13)

Comment: @Andrew, thank you for pointing me to [that](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Timezones2008_UTC%2B13.png), I didn't know that UTC+13 even existed!

Comment: It's actually not that strange once you get used to it. We use UTC on all production systems here at my $work, which makes time calculations so much simpler, so I've gotten quite accustomed to keeping time in both UTC and my local timezone. I have even started to think of 5pm (or 4pm in the winter) as "tomorrow". :)

Comment: I've never found it to be a problem until you travel, in which case I keep my watch and laptop clocks on UTC, and just start thinking about lunchtime as dinner, dinner as sleeptime, sleeptime as breakfast and breakfast as lunch

Comment: Lol I'm at GMT -3

Comment: @Gabriel: SO am I.